# Зависают php процессы

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который поднимает по 5 параллельных процессов в секунду, каждый процесс шлет запрос на апи, после получения ответа умирает и поднимаются следующие 5. Последнее время заметил что иногда процесс отрабатывает и продолжает висеть, либо просто поднимается и висит. Как можно выявить причину зависания?